# Rules Repository Access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Good afternoon,

Can you create access restrictions to a folder and its subfolders?

In this case we have two users: `jorgerocha` and `franciscorocha`, and two repositories (`svn/Folder1/Folder1.1/Folder1.1.1/` and `svn/Folder2/Folder2.1/Folder2.1.1/`) in SVN Edge, with access for all users to these folders set to `read`.

I want to have full access for `jorgerocha` and `franciscorocha` to all of the folders and subfolders (i.e. `svn/Folder1/Folder1.1/Folder1.1.1/` and `svn/Folder2/Folder2.1/Folder2.1.1/`).

Here is an example of what I did:

```
[svn/Folder1]
* = r
franciscorocha = rw
jorgerocha = rw

[svn/Folder2]
* = r
franciscorocha = rw
jorgerocha = rw
```

But in this case I am not able to do anything in these folders with all users. I can only read and write in the first repository.
Is the above correct?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the post but i have already found the solution.

The problem has in the name of the folder.

For example:

```
(WRONG!)
[svn/Folder1]
* = r
franciscorocha = rw
jorgerocha = rw

(RIGHT!)
[Folder1:/]
* = r
franciscorocha = rw
jorgerocha = rw
```

Whit this diference i can access all the information to read the content but if a user don't have the premission to write on the file he can't do it.

Comment: That's fantastic Jorge! Please mark this as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once the 48-hour waiting period has expired. :)